# SharePoint 2010 Workflow: open editable form from parent site list and fill in some fields automatically

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-server

I have a SharePoint 2010 workflow question with 3 main parts to the question:

1. How to open a new item from a different custom list in the edit mode so the user can complete and save
2. Automatically fill in the related fields in the form so the user only has to complete the fields that did not fill in automatically.
3. The list with the edit form is from the parent site and not the sub site that the workflow comes from.

I have found many similar parts of the questions, but haven't been able to put it all together.    I am trying to do this all within SharePoint Designer.
Thanks,
-ab